# Trying to sort list based on string value

Tags: c#, list, sorting

```
gridMessages.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.age));
```

So `age`, is a string that could be something like "0", or "14", you get the picture. I wanted to sort the list by the age, so I convert it to an int in the `OrderBy`. The code compiles and runs without error but the list is not sorted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the results.  `OrderBy` returns a sorted list!

```
gridMessages = gridMessages.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.age));
```

Comment: Not at all, a very common gotcha

Answer (score 0):

If gridMessages is a `List<T>` you can also sort it in place instead of creating a new list:

```
gridMessages.Sort( (a,b) => a.Age.CompareTo(b.Age));
```